# How to add a header key:value pair when publishing a message with pika

Tags: python, rabbitmq, amqp, pika

I am writing an automated test to test a consumer. So far I did not need to include a header when publishing messages but now I do. And it seems like its lacking documentation.

This is my publisher:

```
class RMQProducer(object):

    def __init__(self, host, exchange, routing_key):
        self.host = host
        self.exchange = exchange
        self.routing_key = routing_key

    def publish_message(self, message):
        connection = pika.BlockingConnection(pika.ConnectionParameters(self.host))
        channel = connection.channel()
        message = json.dumps(message)
        channel.basic_publish(exchange=self.exchange,
                              routing_key=self.routing_key,
                              body=message)
```

I want to do smtn like:

```
channel.basic_publish(exchange=self.exchange,
                      routing_key=self.routing_key,
                      body=message,
                      headers={"key": "value"})
```

Whats the correct way to add headers to this message?

Comment: You can take a look at an example I have for pika here, on how to add headers. https://github.com/eandersson/python-rabbitmq-examples/blob/master/Flask-examples/pika_async_rpc_example.py#L113

Comment: You have another example with my own amqp library here as well https://github.com/eandersson/amqpstorm/blob/stable/examples/classic_publisher.py#L16

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You would use [pika.BasicProperties](https://pika.readthedocs.io/en/stable/modules/spec.html#pika.spec.BasicProperties) to add headers.

```
channel.basic_publish(exchange=self.exchange,
                      routing_key=self.routing_key,
                      properties=pika.BasicProperties(
                          headers={'key': 'value'} # Add a key/value header
                      ),
                      body=message)
```

The official documentation for pika does indeed not cover this scenario exactly, but the documentation does have the specifications listed. I would would strongly recommend that you bookmark [this](http://pika.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) page, if you are going to continue using pika.

Answer (score 3):

cant say where i get this, but i do it like:

```
props = pika.BasicProperties({'headers': {'key': 'value'}})
channel.basic_publish(exchange=self.exchange,
                          routing_key=self.routing_key,
                          body=message, properties = props)
```

Answer (score 1):

The official document was mentioned as follows:

```
hdrs = {u'': u' ',
    u'': u'',
    u'': u''}
properties = pika.BasicProperties(app_id='example-publisher',
    content_type='application/json',  
    headers=hdrs)
```

Comment: hdrs dictionary has duplicate keys ;)