# Get transferred file name in RabbitMQ using python pika

Tags: python, rabbitmq, pika, broker, rmq

I'm using pika in Python3 to send CSV files from one node to another and everything is fine here. 
The only thing I need here is to get the transferred file name in the receiving node (e.g: **filename-2017-01-01.csv**)

Are there any ways to do this?

This is the processing part while getting the file.

```
def callback(ch, method, properties, body):
    ch.basic_ack(delivery_tag=method.delivery_tag)
    with open('test.csv', 'wb') as write_csv:
        write_csv.write(body)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of storing the file name with the message, you can use [this method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37698848/1466825) to add a custom header with the file name.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with this idea, for those who want to include the file name with the message:

I've concatenated the file name with the message. After sending the message, I did split on the message:

```
with open(file, 'rb') as csv_file:
    return file + csv_file.read().decode()
```

On the other side:

```
file_name = body.decode().split('.csv')[0]
message = body.decode().split('.csv')[1]
with open('{}.csv'.format(file_name), 'w') as write_csv:
    write_csv.write(message)
```